# Limit fovy in an OpenGL animation

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl

I just wanted to know how can I limit my zoom in/zoom out animation in such a way that the fovy is never exceeded (180 degrees I think), so that the scene does not turn around or do strange things.
The code of the animation is the following:

```
void funSpecial(int key, int x, int y){
    switch(key){
    case GLUT_KEY_UP: zoom+=0.5f; break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN: zoom-=0.5f; break;
    default: zoom=1.0f; break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

It controls the value of the global variable `GLfloat zoom = 1.0f`, which in turn multiplies the value of `fovy`, declared in the definition of the scene with a value of 60. So it does the effect of zooming to the scene.

Comment: Are you asking about `if (fovy * zoom > M_PI) { zoom = M_PI / fovy; }`? It also looks very wrong to set zoom to 0 in the default block if you indeed *multiply* fovy with it.

Comment: Yep, totally right, I'm changing the default value of the switch.

Comment: @giorgioW changing FOV of perspective is cheap/easy way of doing zoom but you might got into trouble due to fisheye effects etc... for extremes is sometime better to use scale ... all depends on the scene and camera position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you just have to limit the value to whatever range it is you want to limit it to. There's basically two ways in which you can do that. You can either make sure that the value is never updated in ways that make it exceed that range:

```
    …
    case GLUT_KEY_UP: zoom = std::min(zoom + 0.5f, max_zoom); break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN: zoom = std::max(zoom - 0.5f, min_zoom); break;
    …
```

Or you just let `zoom` go to whatever value it may go to and clamp the current value to the desired range at the point where you actually use it:

```
    float getZoom() { return std::min(std::max(zoom, min_zoom), max_zoom); }
```

Each approach has its advantages and disadvantages. For example: The first approach requires you to keep your state consistent at all times which can become a much more complex problem than the simple example here would make you think. The second approach might give you isses with underflow/overflow. If you update the value a lot more often than use it, just clamping it in the end avoids the overhead of limiting the range every time the value is updated. Conversely, clamping the value on every use may become a significant overhead in case the value is used much more often than it is updated…